# Why is functional calculus called functional calculus? What does functional mean in functional calculus?

Tags: terminology, banach-algebras, functional-calculus

Given a unital Banach algebra $B$, functional calculus allows one to define $f(a)\in B$ for continuous function $f$ and $a\in B$.

A functional is a mapping from a vector space to its scalar space. But where is the functional in functional calculus? Why is it not called function calculus?

Comment: See [Functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus). Usually, functionals are functions of functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics) In modern linear algebra, it refers to a linear mapping from a vector space V into its field of scalars

Answer (score 0):

I have always understood the term *Functional* to be the noun, that is how functional is the calculus on offer. Of course, we require *a priori* the object of our study to be a function of some sort, represented by some algebra homomorphism for example.